# From where i can find the source code of cp command?

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, cp

See, I want the `cp` command on Android but it doesn't exist so I want to cross compile the source of `cp`.

Linux has cp command, then from where can I find the code of `cp`?

Comment: Which version of android?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cp` is part of [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). There are also different implementations, for example [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/).

It's very strange that there is no `cp` on android. Have you looked thoroughly?

Comment: yes i have double check there is no cp on android mostly people use cat and redirect whole content of file....but i need to do directory copy so can not use that way

Answer (score 5):

Go to this site [coreutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/)
Download the latest archive and go to /src/ there you can find the cp.c file(and many more)

Answer (score 3):

http://coreutils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/7.4/cp_8c-source.html

Answer (score 1):

It is missing on my android as well.

You can work around by using:

```
  cat source > dest
```

Comment: this will only work files. How to handlw whole directory transfer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is in [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/where-i-can-get-source-code-of-the-cp-command-142046/)

From that foram i can download source from here

ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-5.0.tar.gz

In the /src directory after extracting it.

and latest version of core utils can be found here

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/